# Laravel route group middleware issue

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

I keep some laravel routes in the middleware auth group as:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'],function(){

    Route::controller('Activities', 'ActivitiesController');
    Route::get('foo','FooController@getFoo');
    .....
});
```

When I try to login to access these page, I am unable to login and url redirect to login page again and again. But If I use constructor as:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

In those controllers It works perfectly. What is route group problem?

Comment: Do you have A middleware In Activities Controller or FooController constructors? Iike guest middle ware?

Comment: Did you modify app/http/middlewares/Authenticate in anyway?

Comment: No. I keep Authenticate as it was

Comment: This works for me , in route `Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'],function(){
    Route::controller('activities', 'ActivitiesController');
});`  then controller `<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;


class ActivitiesController extends Controller {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        return 'you are in;
    }

}` on attempt to visit /activities I was redirected to login page , and on success back to \activities with 'you are in'. What does your login process looks like?

Comment: which one solved your issue? my code or you figured it out? please accept my answer if I worked

Comment: I figure it out. `Route::controllers(['auth' => 'Auth\AuthController', 'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController']);` was also in the `auth` group thats why I am unable to login.

Comment: okay. good. That's better

Answer (score 3):

Route has a `::middleware` class that you can use:

Routes > web.php

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function(){
  Route::get('/activities', 'ActivitiesController@index');
});
```

You can also use `Route::resource();` which I prefer. If you don't know what it does, here are the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score 1):

This works for me , in route

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'],function(){ 
  Route::controller('activities', 'ActivitiesController'); 
});
```

then controller

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers; 

class ActivitiesController extends Controller { 
    public function getIndex() { 
         return 'you are in; 
    } 
}
```

on attempt to visit /activities I was redirected to login page , and on success back to \activities with 'you are in'.

Comment: first off, Route::controller is being deprecated and will be removed in 5.3 (june). (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0 See deprecations). Secondly I have a very similar situation where I have declared my middleware in a route group and its just skipping right  over it. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the deprecations. About your similar issue, can you open a new question on it. Do give me the link when you do so

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34440256/laravel-5-2-updated-and-route-group-middleware-now-is-no-longer-called

Answer (score 0):

In web.php:

```
$roleGeneral = role1.'~'.role2.'~'.role3.'~'.role4;
Route::group(['middleware' => ['permission.role:'.$roleGeneral]], function() {})
```

In Kernel.php:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [...,
    'permission.role' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckPermission::class,
];
```

In CheckPermission.php:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
{
    $roleArr = explode('~', $role);
    $token = JWTAuth::getToken();
    $user = JWTAuth::toUser($token);
    $roleLogin = SysRoleModel::where('id', $user->role_id)->first();
    if (in_array($roleLogin['name'], $roleArr)){
        return $next($request);
    }else{
        return \Redirect::back()->withMessage('You are not authorized to access!');
    }
}
```