# Laravel 5.2 - Updated and Route group Middleware now is no longer called

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

So I was on the latest Laravel 5.1 and updated to 5.2 today. In my routes I have something like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api']], function() {
    // Members
    Route::get('members', '{api-namespace}\MembersController@index');
    Route::get('member/{id}', '{api-namespace}\MembersController@show');

    // Members Pension
    Route::get('member/{id}/pension/beneficiaries', '{api-namespace}\Inquiry\MembersPensionController@showBeneficiaries');
    Route::get('member/{id}/pension/contributions', '{api-namespace}\Inquiry\MembersPensionController@showContributions');
    Route::get('member/{id}/pension/yearlySummary', '{api-namespace}\Inquiry\MembersPensionController@showYearlySummary');
    Route::get('member/{id}/pension/pensioners', '{api-namespace}\Inquiry\MembersPensionController@showPensioners');

    // Members Summary
    Route::get('member/{id}/beneficiaries/{fund?}', '{api-namespace}\BeneficiariesController@showByMember');
    Route::get('member/{id}/contributions/', '{api-namespace}\ContributionsController@showByMember');

    // Beneficiaries
    Route::get('beneficiaries', '{api-namespace}\BeneficiariesController@index');
    Route::get('beneficiary/{id}', '{api-namespace}\BeneficiariesController@show');

    // Contributions
    Route::get('contributions', '{api-namespace}\ContributionsController@index');

    Route::get('users', '{api-namespace}\UsersController@index');
});
```

The api-version middleware basically checks the header for an api-version and then fills in {api-namespace} in the route actions appropriately. This works fine in 5.1. However, since upgrading I get `Class App\\Http\\Controllers\\{api-namespace}\\MembersController does not exist` and it doesn't even hit my middleware at all. I have a feeling that they may have switched the order of the code so that it validates the route actions BEFORE running middleware because if I put the middleware in globally it works fine. However, I need this api-version group, so if anyone has any ideas how to get around this I am all ears.

As per request:

Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'api-version' => \App\Http\Middleware\ApiVersionMiddleware::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],
        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'api-version',
            'cors'
        ],
    ];
}
```

ApiVersionMiddleware.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Jbm\Exceptions\ApiVersionException;
use Jbm\Helpers\ApiVersion;

class ApiVersionMiddleware
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $route = $request->route();
        $actions = $route->getAction();

        $requestedApiVersion = ApiVersion::get($request);
        if (!ApiVersion::isValid($requestedApiVersion)) {
            throw new ApiVersionException('Invalid API Version');
        }

        $apiNamespace = ApiVersion::getNamespace($requestedApiVersion);

        $actions['uses'] = str_replace(
            '{api-namespace}', $apiNamespace, $actions['uses']
        );

        $route->setAction($actions);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Also notice that I moved my middleware into a middleware group and its still not working. Just an fyi

**Update:**

I tried moving the middleware to global but at that point it has 0 information about the route which means that it can't modify the route to replace `{api-namespace}`. I believe the issue is that the route 'uses' is checked BEFORE middleware is run on it which obviously fails. Can anyone confirm this and / or show me how i would implement something like this in 5.2?

**Update 2:**

So I have discovered the issue. In `Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:834` the router tries to substitute implicit bindings. This happens BEFORE middleware and checks for the route for valid "uses". I have 0 idea how to work around this as it totally blows away what I am currently doing. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's probably something to do with Laravel 5.2 attempting to automatically inject models/classes into the controller calls. See the "Implicit model binding" section of the [Laravel 5.2 release notes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/releases#laravel-5.2)

Comment: im actually thinking it has to do with this: https://mattstauffer.co/blog/middleware-groups-in-laravel-5-2 . They have made middleware groups and the syntax for calling middleware groups is the same as it was to attach middleware to a route group before....so its probably conflicting. Going to test

Comment: The error message implies that it's trying to bind to a model based on your path, but it can't find the model

Comment: Since you mentioned that `api-version` middleware is not receiving any hit at all, check and ensure it has correct namespace, ensure you have registered the middleware in kernel.php inside $routemiddleware, if possible update your question with the whole `api-version` middleware

Comment: I have updated the question.....maybe I need to change up my "tag" for api-namespace to be something that doesn't interfere with implicit model binding?

Comment: I have tried to change the tag to multiple things from <api-namespace> to !api-namespace! and nothing....it keeps on checking the route actions before the middleware is applied for some reason

Comment: Try not using the tag, just pass the fully qualified class name `\App\Http\Middleware\ApiVersionMiddleware::class`

Comment: okay so i moved the ApiVersionMiddleware::class out of the middleware group and into the global middleware. This is because after digging into the core code I realized that the order of operations is as so: 1) run global middleware 2) check routes 3) run route middleware. This obviously does not work for me as I need to change my route THROUGH the middleware. However, now I have an issue because in my apiVersionMiddleware I am doing `$route = $request->route()` and its returning null which is killing everything.

Comment: The above comment may be because you can't get the "route" in global middleware....honestly not sure and if that IS the case im at a catch 22

Comment: @user3158900 I also did what you said and the same thing happens. The routes get checked before they implement the middleware and considering my routes aren't valid till AFTER the middleware runs they fail and send out this error. Correct answer to whomever can show me a workaround to this craziness

Comment: @BillGarrison, You are missing a quote(') in the first line after api: `['middleware' => ['api]]` . Is that an error in code or just a typo in the question?

Comment: Can you try moving {api-version} to the group, like: `Route::group(['middleware' => ['api'], 'namespace' => {api-version}], function() {` and replace  `{api-version}` with actual value

Comment: @Vikas that is a typo I apologize. I also tried to implement what you said but its the same thing as before. All group options are only implemented AFTER the model route is checked due to implicit model bindings. So the route no longer has {api-version} in it but since the ACTUAL controller sits in App\Http\Controllers\v1\ it still doesn't find it and fails out

Comment: Can you update your route group to use just `'api-version'` middleware instead of `api` middleware group and update this in your middleware to use a hard-coded value to verify if it is being accessed or not: `$actions['uses'] = str_replace(
            '{api-namespace}', 'v1', $actions['uses']
        );`

Comment: I actually did exactly this and even put a dd() at the top of the handle method and still nothing. I have come to realize that implicit model binding (which occurs BEFORE middleware is applied) attempts to access the route controller / method in order to get its parameters and inject the model. This happens on line 263 of `Illuminate\Routing\Route.php` and means that, as it stands now, I cannot use custom placeholders in the controller / method of the route. Anyone have any ideas of how i might move forward?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98853/discussion-between-vikas-and-bill-garrison).

Comment: So this question is answered? or not yet? could you please point out what is the obstacle so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this actually ended up being a bug and is now fixed as of the most recent version of laravel 5.2: see here https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11261